# content area not found in my page with elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I just started with Wordpress and I published a website a few weeks ago. Today I wanted to edit the homepage, but I get the following error:

`Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.`

I haven't edited my homepage and it worked perfectly a couple of weeks ago. Is there someone that can help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using any `shortcode` on your page and you are fetching post on that page and looping through the post in a while loop. Please add this after the loop ends. No sure why but this always cause issue for me.

`wp_reset_postdata();`

Code will look like this:

```
$posts= new WP_Query($args);
while ($posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
  .....
  .....
  .....
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It doesn't matter it's a shortcode or what if we are doing something like above make sure to add  `wp_reset_postdata();`

This is one of the issues that I usually face. There can be other reasons too.

Comment: thanks a lot, adding this `wp_reset_postdata();` has resolved the issue, but it has started showing those recent posts at the top in the editor with Elementor mode, but yeah the site is loading properly with the exact layout we designed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've edited the page template from `Templates -> Theme Builder -> Single`. Anyway, even if you don't, you can fix it that way: Go to `Templates -> Theme Builder -> Single -> Add New`, then select `page` and create a template for all single pages (make sure that you drag the page content widget in the template). This should overwrite your theme single page template (which misses the content function).

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your 'Home Page' and 'Posts Page' are different, otherwise you get your page mixed up and this error occurs.. Worked for me!
You can verify this setting in Appearance>Customize>Homepage Settings :)

Answer (score 1):

The Answer to this error is to check the structure of your permalinks. Try to save your permalinks one more time. Also, try to change the permalink structure to “Plain”. Some servers do not allow to write to the .htaccess file and as a matter of fact, you cannot always modify your permalink structure and edit with Elementor.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same place yesterday and freaked for a moment and did some research  to find out why I was receiving the error and came across this page. Believe for me it occurred due to the situation Ed Jones posted about above, I had inadvertently edited the post template. But a fast and easy fix was to go back to an earlier revision of the page in my history. That solved my problem quickly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28283972)

Comment: Okay, will not comment on any posts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add `the_content()` at the end of your templates

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, it was a slug change within the page. That was so weird and I don't know why it happened that way. But this may help someone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).